# Construction of $C^1$/$H^2$-conforming finite element basis for triangular or tetrahedral mesh

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

In the paper [Hierarchical Conforming Finite Element Methods for the Biharmonic Equation](http://epubs.siam.org/sinum/resource/1/sjnaam/v29/i6/p1610_s1), P. Oswald claimed Clough-Tocher type elements has $C^1$-continuity while being a cubic polynomial on each triangle. He didn't give a set of explicit basis functions just the standard degrees of freedom on the quadrature points.

Similarly, in the book [The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods](http://books.google.com/books?id=ci4c_R0WKYYC) Chapter 3, the authors give us the construction of cubic Hermite finite elements, but they didn't mention the continuity of the cubic Hermite elements.

However, in the paper [Differential complexes and numerical stability](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/papers/icm2002.pdf), Doulgas Arnold proposed that for $C^1$/$H^2$-conforming discrete space we should use the Hermite quintic(or rather Argyris) finite elements, which is very complicated to express explicitly.

So here are my questions:

(1) Is there any paper that comes up with an explicit formula for the $C^1$/$H^2$-conforming finite elements on triangular or tetrahedral mesh?

(2) Should piecewise cubic be the minimal degree of polynomials requirement for $C^1$-continuity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cubic Hermite elements have a continuous normal derivative but not full $ C^1 $ continuity.  In particular, the normal derivatives may not match at the boundary of two elements, away from the vertices.  If you want full $ C^1 $ continuity you will have to use the Argyris element or Hsieh-Clough-Tucker or something.  I recommend the discussion in chapter 6 of Ciarlet's finite element book.

The degree of polynomial required for $ C^1 $ continuity will depend on your spatial dimension, but in 2D or 3D I don't think you can get away with less than cubic polynomials.  You could consider some kind of nonconforming method which may allow a simpler finite element space.

Comment: Err, if a function is continuous across the interface between two cells, and if the function on each cell is in $C^\infty$ as it must be if it's a polynomial, then how can the tangential derivative be discontinuous on a cell interface? Or did you mean that the tangential derivative can be discontinuous *at the vertices, i.e. the end-points of each interface*?

Comment: You're absolutely right, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I refer you to the book [Splines on Triangulations](http://books.google.com.sa/books?id=6hvqGgbBmEoC&dq=Spline%20Functions%20on%20Triangulations&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=hg_HSYazN82ktwf_vrTJCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Spline%20Functions%20on%20Triangulations&f=false). I cannot locate my copy at the moment to give you a better answer, but I recall a discussion/theorems on the polynomial order required for $C^1$ spaces. If I recall correctly, Lai proves that under certain conditions $p=3$ is OK, but $p=5$ is always sufficient.

Unfortunately, I also remember that Lai does not then show how to construct $C^1$ spaces, only prove they exist given a triangulation and a spline space. Once he has this proof, he solves his application with additional linear constraint equations to enforce the $C^1$ condition.

Comment: welcome to scicomp Mr. Collier :)

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to the following pages for a full listing of the basis functions for Argyris: [FEMList.pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3acfhKf4TBHjQJ%3adl.gna.org/getfem/doc/getfemlist.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShFFbsULh4EhCil4EAA9eszMUUsAP4V49EJuma29lp4FGTBLDtFyolmO_dluDlfcAd1MUPTjKfGxrmkg_RhPb_HQFzkY8LATLTibe22PJo9Z1QwV5RWC0iy9ChB6mJXq_UXLpGq&sig=AHIEtbTVogm9ZLw4lXgTvsRp1sf2nL3R2w) [Wikipedia entry (French)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonctions_d%27Argyris)

Also, you can use the [VT-ICAM ArgyrisPack](https://github.com/VT-ICAM/ArgyrisPack) that a colleague and I developed.